# Upgrade from VMware ESXi 5.1 to 5.5

Tags: iso-image, esxi

I am quite new to VMware ESXi. I have used `esxcli` to do a patch update.
I would like to ask if we can actually do an upgrade from ESXi 5.1 to 5.5?

All I have is an ISO. I understand most of the commands is for zip, wondering if I can do ISO on the CMD.

Can I actually do this command?

```
esxcli software vib update -d /vmfs/volumes/Datastore01/<Esx file>.ISO
```

Do help, thank you and regards.

Comment: [Yes](https://wojcieh.net/upgrade-esxi-5-1-to-5-5-part-3-esxcli/)

Answer (score 0):

The esxcli does not use the iso, but resources obtained from vmware:

From [vSphere documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.upgrade.doc/GUID-E51C5DB6-F28E-42E8-ACA4-0EBDD11DF55D.html)

> Upgrading ESXi with esxcli commands requires an understanding of VIBs, image profiles, and software depots.
>
> [...]

To upgrade with the ISO, AFAIK, you must boot from it.